# Reading a string till a key word and replacing from there with another string

Tags: sed, awk, grep, string

I am new to UNIX and am practising shell scripting. I have an application where I need string searching and replacement.

There are some lines in a file 1 and file 2. I have a search key word. If the key word is present in file 1 and file 2 then the sting after the key word in file 2 should be replaced with the string after the key word in file 1.

for example:

file 1:

abc def ghi jkl **unix** is the key

This file contains 3 lines and **unix** is the key

file 2 :

This is a sample sentence **unix** in the second file

This is line 2 and **unix** the new line in the second file

The key word is "unix".Here the string after unix in file file 1 is "is the key" so the string after the "unix" in file 2 i.e "in the second file" should be replaced with "is the key". so after the string reading and replacement the output of file should look like

file 1:

abc def ghi jkl **unix** is the key

This file contains 3 lines and **unix** is the key

file 2 :

This is a sample sentence **unix** is the key

This is line 2 and **unix** is the key

I used the following commands separately

```
 grep sed awk
```

But I am unable to figure out how can search and replacement can be combined.
can any one tell me how the above can be done.any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Don't do cross-posting.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396899/reading-a-string-till-a-key-word-and-replacing-from-there-with-another-string-in)

Answer (score 1):

This will work for the sample files you provided

`replacement=$(sed -n 's/^.*unix\(.*$\)/\1/p'  file1)
 sed -i "s/^\(.*unix\).*$/\1$replacement/" file2`

Assumption is that the first file have the only one possible value of string after the unix keyword which can only be once per line.

Brief explanation of how it works, as requested.

those two lines supposed to be wrapped in a shell script.
Regexp for the 1st sed extracts the part of the line that follows the **unix** keyword from the 1st file.
**replacemnet** variable gets that part useing `$()` command substitution
then in the second line that variable is used to replace the part of lines after the keyword in the second file.

Comment: can you give an example of how it works

Comment: I believe the answer contains the example.
Did you mean an explanation?

Comment: yes please. could you ?

Comment: sure
I've extended the answer with a brief explanation.